# Openbox keybindings not taking effect after --reconfigure or restarting X

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, openbox, lxde

```
 273     <keybind key="W-Return">
 274       <action name="Execute">
 275         <command>lxterminal</command>
 276       </action>
 277     </keybind>
 278     <keybind key="W-Up">
 279       <action name="ToggleMaximizeFull"/>
 280     </keybind>
 281     <keybind key="W-Left">
 282       <action name="MoveToEdgeWest"/>
 283     </keybind>
 284     <keybind key="W-Right">
 285       <action name="MoveToEdgeEast"/>
 286     </keybind>
```

I added these lines in between the default last `</keybind>` and `</keyboard>` in my `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` file (the line numbers are from vim). However, neither restarting X nor issuing an `openbox --reconfigure` applies these settings.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Arch with all the default LXDE packages.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the file in the proper path?

Comment: Did you receive any error dialog ? If so, the configure xml file is malformed

Comment: Pastebin and link to the complete `rc.xml` - a fragment is not that useful...

Answer (score 19):

There is also

```
$ openbox --restart
```

Since it was not mentioned yet, I will do it.
This will **not** restart X as well.
Presumably `--restart` is "more powerful" than `--reconfigure`.

Comment: Does this close the running GUI applications?

Comment: To answer question in comment, it did not restart my GUI browser on openbox restart.

Answer (score 11):

On LXDE `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` config is used instead.

To check how openbox was started you can do:

```
$ ps ax | grep openbox
 2109 ?        S      0:29 openbox --config-file /home/marcin/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
```

Comment: on `lxqt` it is `lxqt-rc.xml`. btw you can either use `a` or `x` flag with `ps`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the path in your home directory

`.config/openbox/rc.xml`

not

`~./config/openbox/rc.xml`

Comment: That is where it is; I made a typo in the OP.

Comment: Does it work now? If yes, you can mark the answer as the correct one.

Comment: Nope. Nevertheless, I've gone ahead and switched to xfwm4, but if this question accumulates more answers I'll go and test them.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i've been struggling with the same problem for an hour now and the answer i'm afraid is quite silly and straightforward.
You should locate you keybinds within the keyboard block inside the rc.xml other wise they won't work.

I hope i answered your question :).